# Fill multiple nulls for categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, null, categorical-data

I'm wondering if there is a pythonic way to fill nulls for categorical data by randomly choosing from the distribution of unique values. Basically proportionally / randomly filling categorical nulls based on the existing distribution of the values in the column...

-- below is an example of what I'm already doing

--I'm using numbers as categories to save time, I'm not sure how to randomly input letters

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed([1])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(10, 2, 20).round().astype(object))
df.rename(columns = {0 :  'category'}, inplace = True)
df.loc[::5] = np.nan
print df

   category
0       NaN
1        12
2         4
3         9
4        12
5       NaN
6        10
7        12
8        13
9         9
10      NaN
11        9
12       10
13       11
14        9
15      NaN
16       10
17        4
18        9
19        9
```

This is how I'm currently inputting the values

```
df.category.value_counts()

9     6
12    3
10    3
4     2
13    1
11    1

df.category.value_counts()/16

9     0.3750
12    0.1875
10    0.1875
4     0.1250
13    0.0625
11    0.0625

# to fill categorical info based on percentage
category_fill = np.random.choice((9, 12, 10, 4, 13, 11), size = 4, p = (.375, .1875, .1875, .1250, .0625, .0625))
df.loc[df.category.isnull(), "category"] = category_fill
```

Final output works, just takes a while to write

```
df.category.value_counts()

9     9
12    4
10    3
4     2
13    1
11    1
```

Is there a faster way to do this or a function that would serve this purpose?

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`stats.rv_discrete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html):

```
from scipy import stats

counts = df.category.value_counts()
dist = stats.rv_discrete(values=(counts.index, counts/counts.sum()))
fill_values = dist.rvs(size=df.shape[0] - df.category.count())
df.loc[df.category.isnull(), "category"] = fill_values
```

EDIT: For general data(not restricted to integers) you can do:

```
dist = stats.rv_discrete(values=(np.arange(counts.shape[0]), 
                                 counts/counts.sum()))
fill_idxs = dist.rvs(size=df.shape[0] - df.category.count())
df.loc[df.category.isnull(), "category"] = counts.iloc[fill_idxs].index.values
```

Comment: This works great on the test data! But when I try and use it on data that are strings I get the error.

"could not convert string to float: b"

My fault for not using data that are string in the sample. Is there any way for it to work on strings in addition or instead?

Thanks!

Comment: @DavidFeldman, glad to help. You almost had it all figured out.